# Angular Typescript Array filter collection base of array of values like SQL "in"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular and typescript to filter an array of nested collection and need to filter the nest collection based on an array of months.

The complex array looks something like this

```
{
    Columns: [{
        name: string,
        myData: [{
            monthName: string,
            note: string
        }, ...]
    }, ...]
}
```

In the Columns collection, there is are 12 nested object for each month of the year.

I have any array of filter values like `{'January', 'Febuary' 'March'}`, so there are many combination.

I am figuring out how to filter based on the `filtervalues = {'January', 'Febuary' 'March'}`

Something like this

`var filterColumns = Columns[0].myData.filter(f => f.monthName in filtervalues);`

So if the Columns started with Columns with 12 myData for Jan thru Dec, I can do a filter for Jan, Feb, Mar and the filterColumns get a Columns with 3 myData nested object with monthName of Jan, Feb, and Mar.

is there an easy way to do this on nested collection in typescript?

Thanks

Comment: Don't try to explain, instead please post your JSON ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `filterValues` should be an `Array`:

```
const filterValues = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
```

Then you can use the [`.includes()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
let filterColumns = Columns[0].myData.filter(f => filterValues.includes(f.monthName));
```